# In R, I have multiple data.frame with different length in same variable at matrix but i want to make them one data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

How should I merge them in at one ?

```
mat<-as.matrix(x=c(df1,df2),y=c(df3,df4,df5,df6),z=c(df7,df8,df9,df10))
```

dim(mat)  #  1 x 3

I want to merge data.frame of y<-c(df3,df4,df5,df6) for all x, y and z in same variable as matrix 
result should be matrix of same dimension 1 x 3

Is there technique to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(df1, df2, df3, ...))
```